# Can we add new consortium to Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Can we add new consortium to hyperledger fabric? what will be the typical use-case for adding new consortium to the fabric network.?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add organization to app.

Here you have tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKuGU5CYV_E